# npm install is not installing + grunt-contrib.copy not found

Tags: json, node.js

I have two questions.  I am completing a project from the book "Learning to Program", and am a little confused as to why npm is not installing, and why I am receiving another error message. I'm using Windows, I have installed node.js (v0.12.2) and have attempted to install grunt:  `npm install -g grunt-cli`

**Question 1** - When I try to install npm, it does not list all of the dependencies defined in package.json.

The following shows when I try to install npm in my main directory:

```
C:\Users\Me\My Documents\kittenbook\npm install
npm WARN package.json kittenbook@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN package.json kittenbook@0.0.1 No repository field
npm WARN package.json kittenbook@0.0.1 No README data
```

From what I see, it's supposed to display a bunch of lines after those three warnings, such as:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-concat
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-copy
```

and so on.

**Question 2:**
This is probably because installing npm is not working correctly, but when I try to run "grunt jshint" it gives me this error:

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-.copy" not found.  Is it installed?

Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
>> 2 files lint free

Done, without errors.
```

Sorry for this very unorganized question, but I am very new to programming and I am very confused as to where the problem is.

Here is some more information.

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Project configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            release: {
                src: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js'],
                dest: 'release/main.js'
            }
        },
        copy: {
            release: {
                src: 'manifest.json',
                dest: 'release/manifest.json'
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            files: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js']
            }
        });

    // Load Grunt plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib.copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

    // Register Tasks
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'copy']);
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "kittenbook",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.2",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0"
    }
}
```

If you need other information I will gladly get it to you.  Thank you all so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`grunt-contrib.copy` should be `grunt-contrib-copy` (use dash, not period)

Comment: Doh!  This certainly fixed the problem.  Thanks for the quick response and if I have another question I'll reach out to you Moogs!